# How to generate a simple filename that is non duplicate on existing folder?

Tags: vb.net

I have a console application. I get the console application's folder path via this code:

```
dim Folder as string
Folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)
```

And I need to create a new file with this name `Key.txt` in the same folder as the console application. Because this file name is rather normal and there is possible duplicate in that folder. How do I prevent duplicate file name while still using simple name for that file?

Comment: Can you please define simple? Do you mean only dictionary words or something without digits/symbols or anything else.

Comment: Maybe Key1.txt, Key2.txt is ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just append the date and time to the file name.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to check if that file exists and if it does add an additional identifier (like an incremented number) to make it unique if it does exist.

**Example**:

```
Dim Folder As String
Folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)
Dim Filename As String = Folder & "Key.txt"

Dim fileToCreate As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(Filename)
Dim i As Integer = 1
While (fileToCreate.Exists())
    fileToCreate = New System.IO.FileInfo(Folder & "Key (" & i.ToString() & ").txt")
End While

'create the file either directly or via another mechanism, 
'   but you have a valid filename at this point at least
fileToCreate.Create()
```